# C++: two functions, each takes enum parameter, signatures match?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, enums

In the scenario where two functions exist and both accept an enum as a parameter (different enums), can a single type of function pointer refer to them both?

```
enum MyEnum1 {...};
enum MyEnum2 {...};

void blah( MyEnum1 one );
void guff( MyEnum2 two );

void (*pFunc[2]) ( int );

pFunc[0] = blah;
pFunc[1] = guff;
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: type safety is your friend. any reason to do this?

Comment: I'm trying to understand some code for an input library. Essentially, imagine there are objects representing physical input devices (keyboard, mouse etc.) and there are so-called logical devices that are an abstraction on top of the physical devices. Logical devices map physical input to some action. The input can be any combination of physical input from device(s). The objects representing the physical devices implement the same interface, which takes an enum representing a given button or key. Then you build up the inputs. Perhaps I've misunderstood why the signatures need to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the enum types are not implicitly convertible, much less the same exact type.  You could easily do what you want by making the functions take an int and cast it to the enum with validation at the top.

Comment: To clarify then, enum types won't be implicitly cast to int?

Comment: And the example function pointer (that takes an int) can't hold a pointer to a function that takes an enumerated type?

Comment: "with validation" - assuming the enum ranges don't overlap? I really don't like the idea...

Comment: @ScottOliver: that's correct.  You can easily test it with your own compiler.

Comment: I'd just like to add, that though this is [correct](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e99a02558c5c35d0), enums will be implicitly cast to int when passed as a parameter. See [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70a0dd2cd29643cc). Which is what I ended up going with.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way to do this?

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve with having one function take 2 kinds of parameters.

C++ overloaded functions support having the same function with different parameters.

```
    #include "stdio.h"

    enum Enum1
    {
        E1_one,
        E1_two
    };

    enum Enum2
    {
        E2_one,
        E2_two
    };

    class Foo
    {
    public:
        void Bar(Enum1 e1)
        {
            printf("Function parameter Enum1\n");    
        }

        void Bar(Enum2 e2)
        {
            printf("Function parameter Enum2\n");
        }
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv[])
    {
        Foo foo;
        foo.Bar(E1_one);
        foo.Bar(E2_two);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's not about being able to supply either of the enums to the same function, but about using a single type of pointer that can refer to a function that takes an enum, therefore being able to store a pointer to either of the example functions.

Comment: What you need sounds like a base class with a virtual function which takes an enum. You store as a base class pointer and invoke the virtual function.